# How to block warnings inside a method

Tags: python, twitter

So I'm using method_x from a third party library which prints a warning every time I use it. Since I'm coding something that is meant to get user input from the cli I want to block this annoying prints.

```
import module_x

module_x.method_x() # Has expected behaviour but prints an annoying warning
```

Is there something I can do to block all the print statements inside a function? Maybe wrapping the method with something or disable stdout temporarily?

**Edit**: I ended up using a method of the logging module that captures the warnings and redirects them to a log file. Here's the decorator I made:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='log/log', level=logging.WARNING)

class redirect_warnings_to_log(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, args):
            logging.captureWarnings(True)
            self.f(args)
            logging.captureWarnings(False)
```

And here's the decorated method that was printing the warnings:

```
@redirect_warnings_to_log
def tweet(message):
    twt = api.PostUpdate(message)
```

Comment: This depends on exactly how `method_x` is producing output. Writing to standard output? Writing to standard error? Using the `warnings` or `logging` modules?

Comment: I looked into the library and it was actually using warnings. Anand answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the question says -

> I'm using method_x from a third party library which **prints a warning** every time I use it.

If `method_x` is using Python's [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) module. Then you can use [`warnings.catch_warnings()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) along with `with` statement and [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) to ignore the warnings , so that warnings are suppressed.

Example -

```
>>> import warnings
>>> def f():
...     warnings.warn("Some warning!")
...
>>> f()
__main__:2: UserWarning: Some warning!
>>> with warnings.catch_warnings():
...     warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
...     f()
...
```

Please note this only temporarily suppress warnings, only within the `with` block, in the f() is used outside the `if` block, then it does not suppress those warnings.

---

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)

> While within the context manager all warnings will simply be ignored. This allows you to use known-deprecated code without having to see the warning while not suppressing the warning for other code that might not be aware of its use of deprecated code. Note: this can only be guaranteed in a single-threaded application. If two or more threads use the catch_warnings context manager at the same time, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I looked at the library on Github and it was using the warnings module indeed. Your answer was just what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to actually catch the warnings so I can redirect them to a log file?

Comment: Yes, it is given in the documentation part - https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings
. Do something like `with warnings.catch_warnings() as list_of_warnings:` , and don't add the filter . Then as new warnings come, it is added to that `list_of_warnings` and if you want you can write it out to a file or do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is actually using a print statement than temporarily redirect `stdout` (or `stderr`) might be the best option.

A simple way of doing this:

```
import os
import sys

original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Call your function here

sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Comment: You don't actually need to save the original stdout yourself; it's always available as `sys.__stdout__`.

Comment: While that assumption might be correct in many cases, perhaps it was already replaced by something else. It could break testing code for example. This seemed a slightly safer answer.

Comment: Anand gave the answer I needed. Yours feels more appropiate for the previous question title but I didn't know the library could be using the warnings module. I wish I could accept both answers :(

Comment: @Phob1a: no worries, glad you have the problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decorator to catch one specific warning to apply to your method :

```
import functools
import warnings
from typing import Type


def ignore_warning(warning: Type[Warning]):
    """
    Ignore a given warning occurring during method execution.

    Args:
        warning (Warning): warning type to ignore.

    Returns:
        the inner function

    """

    def inner(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category= warning)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return inner


def my_method_no_decorator(*args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    warnings.warn("WARNING", UserWarning)

    return True

@ignore_warning(UserWarning)
def my_method_decorator(*args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    warnings.warn("WARNING", UserWarning)

    return True


my_method_no_decorator()
<input>:2: UserWarning: WARNING
True

my_method_decorator()
True
```

Comment: The warning isn't suppressed if I import "ignore_warning" from a different file. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, may you tell me what is your project structure ? On me side, I import this method without issues.